# How to add a fixed value to the Y axis in Altair?

Tags: python, data-science, altair

I'm new to Altair and I'd like to add a two rule lines on the Y axis of a stock progression in my line chart.

The DataFrame `symbol_data` has Date, Symbol, Name, Close, and I added another column "StdDev" which is the standard deviation for the entire data set.

```py
chart = alt.Chart(symbol_data).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x=alt.X("Date:T", title="Dates"),
    y=alt.X("Close", title="Close price"),
  )
)

line = alt.Chart(symbol_data).mark_rule(
    color="red", 
  ).encode(
    y=alt.Y("mean(Close)" + StdDev),
)

line2 = alt.Chart(symbol_data).mark_rule(
    color="blue",
  ).encode(
    y=alt.Y("mean(Close)" - StdDev),
)

chart + line + line2
```

I'm trying to add the standard deviation lines by adding and subtracting from the Y axis values.  I know this isn't valid but is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?

```py
...  
    y=alt.Y("mean(Close)" + StdDev),
...
```

I've tried adding a mark area which is conceptually close to what I want but I want two rule lines.

```py
line2 = alt.Chart(symbol_data).mark_area(
    opacity=0.5, color="gray"
      ).encode(
      x=alt.X("Date:T"),
      y=alt.Y("max(Close):Q"),
      y2=alt.Y2("StdDev"),
  )
```

Update: I was able to get the desired result but I had to add columns to the DataFrame; one for the +1 standard deviation and another for -1 standard deviation.  I'd still like to know if I can add or subtract from the Y axis values.

```py
  upper_std = alt.Chart(symbol_data).mark_rule(
      color="green",
      strokeDash=(6, 2)).encode(
      y=alt.Y("Std_plus:Q"),
  )
      
  line = alt.Chart(symbol_data).mark_rule(
      color="red", 
      strokeWidth=2, 
      strokeDash=(5, 2)).encode(
      y=alt.Y("mean(Close):Q"),
  )
      
  lower_std = alt.Chart(symbol_data).mark_rule(
      color="blue",
      strokeDash=(6, 2)).encode(
      y=alt.Y("Std_minus:Q"),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add a standard deviation is to [let Altair compute it](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/errorbars_with_std.html) for you by using the raw data and `extend='stdev'`:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

error_bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_errorbar(extent='stdev').encode(
  x=alt.X('yield').scale(zero=False),
  y=alt.Y('variety')
)

points = alt.Chart(source).mark_point(filled=True, color='black').encode(
  x=alt.X('mean(yield)'),
  y=alt.Y('variety'),
)

error_bars + points
```

If you only have access to the aggregate data, you can compute it by using `transform_calculate` [like so](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/simple_scatter_with_errorbars.html):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some data points with uncertainties
np.random.seed(0)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = np.random.normal(10, 0.5, size=len(x))
yerr = 0.2

# set up data frame
source = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y, "yerr": yerr})

# the base chart
base = alt.Chart(source).transform_calculate(
    ymin="datum.y-datum.yerr",
    ymax="datum.y+datum.yerr"
)

# generate the points
points = base.mark_point(
    filled=True,
    size=50,
    color='black'
).encode(
    alt.X('x').scale(domain=(0, 6)),
    alt.Y('y').scale(zero=False)
)

# generate the error bars
errorbars = base.mark_errorbar().encode(
    x="x",
    y="ymin:Q",
    y2="ymax:Q"
)

points + errorbars
```